# how to impalement automated test of SMSOTP on WSO2 platform

Tags: automated-tests, wso2-identity-server

I need to test some features on WSO2 Identity Server (IS) in automatic way. specifically the MFA implementation using SMSOTP. This case study refers to implementing an automated test of log in using SMSOTP like the second authentication factor. To do this, we need to obtain the code to be sent via SMS to validate it without receiving it on a cell phone :). Until now WSO2 Identity Server (IS) provides admin API to validate and resend the validation SMS code, but those API do not show the code on the response, this is necessary to can automate the test.

(https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/enable-verification-for-updated-mobile-number, https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS511/apidocs/self-registration/).

One solution is use to the WSO2 Identity Server (IS) SMS OTP Authenticator.

(https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-sms-otp)

this extension exposes an endpoint to validate the SMS code, but I am not sure that endpoint shows the validation code.

I need a way to can obtain that validation code (not in cell phone) to can validate flow from a test script.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is imperative to not to send the OTP codes in the API call responses since it is a secret known by the Identity Server and shared only with the user's mobile. So I believe if you want to specifically automate MFA using SMS OTP, you have to go in the correct workflow and do the proper validation. If you specifically consider the SMS OTP flow, you have to validate,

- if your SMS sender is working fine
- if the OTP validation flow is working fine in the Identity Server

There are different tools you can use to automate SMS workflows, such as mailinator. You can get a mobile number from such a service and use the APIs available with that service to retrieve the SMS received to the user to implement the automated test.